# IE browser events delphi

Tags: windows, delphi

I'm trying with delphi to catch browser evens like document complete, or before navigate. I found a intresting pas unit which can do that only for win xp.

```
[DCC Warning] IEEvents.pas(285): W1002 Symbol 'DWebBrowserEvents2' is specific to a platform

constructor TIEEvents.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  // Perform inherited
  inherited Create(AOwner);

  // Set the event sink IID
  FSinkIID := DWebBrowserEvents2;
end;
```

However, I want to make it work on highest platforms like win7 or win8. Please if you can help fix this issue or you can come with a different example which will help me then i will thankful for you.

Comment: Standard TWebBrowser has these events and it should work fine. Do you have Delphi environment new enough to support windows 7/8?

Comment: @eis I want to add events dinamically because browser is created dinamically. do you know how to do this?

Comment: `yourwb1.DocumentComplete := YourHandler;` ? IIRC it should work like that, if you're working with TWebBrowser

Comment: I'm not working with TWebBrowser. but I work with IWebbrowser2

Comment: Wouldn't be easier for you implement `IDispatch::Invoke` method for the `IWebBrowser2` interface and make a case of `dispIdMember` parameter for the DISPIDs of the `DWebBrowserEvents2` methods like a `TWebBrowser` implementation does ?

Comment: @TLama maybe, post your comment as answer and i will vote up, if no better answers will come in then i will select your answers as closest to what i need. thanks